# JavaFX integration in your Java 7 application

Tags: java, javafx

I've reached the stage of distribution of my JavaFX application, but I got into a big problem. In java 8 javafx is automatically included in your jre, but in java 7 it is not. I dont know how to bundle it with my application, and java 7 users cant run my app, while java 8 users can run it perfectly. I've searched it everywhere and I cant seem to find a solution. I am using Netbeans JRE with maven integration. So far i've tried javafx maven plugin, without success, javafxpackager but I don't know if I am following the right path or if I am just doing unrelated things.

Comment: Java7 users should upgrade.

Comment: A huge part of the java users are still using java 7, I cant simply force everyone to use java 8. We are talking about thousands of users..

Comment: You could package the JRE with your app.  Then users won't be relying on thier own java install ind instead use the one you provide so you can be sure that there are no version properties.

Comment: That was something that I thought about too, but could not find much searching, any help?

Comment: The standard deployment for JavaFX 2.2 will bundle JavaFX with the application. The [standard deployment documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/) also shows you how to bundle the JRE with the application to build a "Self contained application package". FWIW, I do not recommend JavaFX 2.2 for production and would strongly recommend JavaFX 8 as a minimum.

Comment: "A huge part of the java users are still using java 7". Hmm. I don't think it's unreasonable to require an up-to-date Java runtime on the desktop if the user is expecting to run a Java desktop application. At the time of writing, Java 7 is quite long out of public support. (Server-side Java is a different issue: you need to wait for the application servers to catch up with later versions.) But, as mentioned, a self-contained application package is probably the way to go.